# Assigning features to teams rather than assigning front-end or back-end work?

Tags: agile, team-management, software-development

The system that i work on has a front-end and a back-end. At the moment, my team is working on the UI tasks and other team is working on the back-end tasks. There is also another team which handles legacy system tasks. Our target is to retire the legacy system and replace it with the new one which has a front-end and a back-end.

There are about 8 members in each team.

Going forward, management has decide to shuffle above mentioned teams and another team to create 4 teams, each containing 8 members.

Each team will be working on a feature of the system (front-end and back-end work). Any single team won't own the back-end or the front-end.

We follow agile and Will this approach be good when going forward or do we have to make any other suggestions to make this work?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Working software is the primary measure of progress.

A front-end without a back-end is not working software in my book, ofcourse you need a single team that creates a fully working piece of functionality. To be able to deliver working features end-2-end you need a cross-functional team. Meaning the team should be able to execute all neccacary disciplines to make a full working product.

[image]

Slicing vertically should be an Agile teams main focus, delivering working software each iteration.

**Workshop**

There is a training exercise you can try to get better in making smaller vertical slices and getting everyone to understand the concept, its called Elephant Carpaccio:

> The Elephant Carpaccio exercise is a great way for software people to
>   practice & learn how to break stories into really thin vertical
>   slices. It also leads to interesting discussions about quality and
>   tech practices.

- [Elephant Carpaccio exercise](http://alistair.cockburn.us/Elephant+Carpaccio+exercise) by [Alistair Cockburn](https://twitter.com/TotherAlistair).
- Detailed step-by-step: https://docs.google.com/document/d/1TCuuu-8Mm14oxsOnlk8DqfZAA1cvtYu9WGv67Yj_sSk/pub

Comment: No point even adding another post. Niels nails it in one. I use the cake slice vs. cake layer analogy all the time. You will find you are going to get more done in this new manner. Kudos to your management for a wise move.